# Difference between a convex hull and alpha shape

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

What is the difference between a convex hull and alpha shape? What I get to understand from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape), is that, alpha shape generates a set of boundary points such that together they form a smaller surface area when considering the selected points than a normal convex hull. I am unable to understand the difference mathematically. Can someone please explain it in a simple way if possible?

Comment: alpha shapes aren't necessarily [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry i know that. Got the info from wiki. But can't understand the mathematical difference between the two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an alpha shape you fix the radius of a circle and define a starting point (SP). Then you rotate the circle with its circumference on the SP until it hits another point. Then transfer the circle to this point and repeat.

With a convex hull, the 'finding object' (FO) is a line.

A good picture to demonstrate this, from [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/), is:

[image: alpha shape]

Another way of visualizing an alpha hull is to use a line of fixed length as the FO. A problem is that the FO might not hit anything - this defines the minimum resolution of a set of points.

An advantage of a circular FO is the final object can be rendered 'curvy'.

Comment: i am still unable to understand ....

Comment: The gist is that the the convex hull formed using in this procedure depends on the size of the circle that you use. If you use a small circle the hull won't be convex. If you use a very very large circle then you'd get the convex hull.